# Elixir: How can I describe mix.exs settings correctly?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I tried to write a web scraping tool by using HTTPoison. As a first step, I wrote a short HTTP accessing code along the steps shown below;

1. Create a project by mix

   $ mix new httptest1
2. Write a short code on lib/httptest1.ex.

   ```
   defmodule Httptest1 do
     require HTTPoison

     def test1 do
       ret = HTTPoison.get! "http://www.yahoo.com"
       %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body} = ret
       IO.inspect body
     end
   end

   Httptest1.test1()
   ```
3. Modify mix.exs for HTTPoison.

   ```
   defmodule Httptest1.Mixfile do
     use Mix.Project

     def project do
       [app: :httptest1,
        version: "0.0.1",
        elixir: "~> 1.0",
        build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
        start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
        deps: deps]
     end

     # Configuration for the OTP application
     def application do
       [applications: [:logger, :httpoison]]
     end

     # Dependencies can be Hex packages:
     #
     defp deps do
       [
        {:httpoison, "~> 0.6"}
       ]
     end
   end
   ```
4. Run `$ mix deps.get` for dependency.
5. Run `$ mix run`, then compilation failed;

   ```
   ==> idna (compile)
   Compiled src/idna.erl
   Compiled src/idna_ucs.erl
   Compiled src/punycode.erl
   (... snip ...)
   Generated httpoison app

   == Compilation error on file lib/httptest1.ex ==
   ** (exit) exited in: :gen_server.call(:hackney_manager, {:new_request, #PID<0.154.0>, #Reference<0.0.1.1724>, {:client, :undefined, :hackney_dummy_metrics, :hackney_tcp_transport, 'www.yahoo.com', 80, "www.yahoo.com", [connect_timeout: 5000, recv_timeout: :infinity], nil, nil, nil, true, :hackney_pool, :infinity, false, 5, false, 5, nil, nil, nil, :undefined, :start, nil, :normal, false, false, false, false, nil, :waiting, nil, 4096, "", [], :undefined, nil, nil, nil, nil, :undefined, nil}}, :infinity)
       ** (EXIT) no process
       (stdlib) gen_server.erl:212: :gen_server.call/3
       src/hackney_client/hackney_manager.erl:66: :hackney_manager.init_request/1
       src/hackney_client/hackney_manager.erl:56: :hackney_manager.new_request/1
       src/hackney_connect/hackney_connect.erl:181: :hackney_connect.socket_from_pool/4
       src/hackney_connect/hackney_connect.erl:36: :hackney_connect.connect/5
       src/hackney_client/hackney.erl:319: :hackney.request/5
       lib/httpoison.ex:60: HTTPoison.request/5
       lib/httpoison.ex:60: HTTPoison.request!/5
   ```

When I used `$ iex -S mix` instead, the result was same.

But if I moved httptest1.ex to the same directory where mix.exs was placed, like `$ mv lib/httptest1.ex .` and tried to specify the source file explicitly; `$ mix run httptest1`, it worked correctly.

**Question:**
I suspect my mix.exs setting goes something wrong, what's that?

Comment: I had similar error message. The code executes properly in IEX with no error, but throws error when run a mix task. The solution that worked for me is "HTTPoison.start" Maybe this helps someone with similar error message in another case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `.ex` in `lib/` are compiled. Since Elixir is meta-programming language when you compile a file you are actually running the code. Which means that `Httptest1.test1()` is executed when you compile your project.

HTTPoison needs to be started for it work correctly. It is started when your application starts which it is when you do `mix run ...`. But when your project is compiling your project or your dependencies are not started so calls to your dependencies might fail.

Check out this chapter [Supervisor and Application](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html) in the getting started guide to learn how to run code when your application starts.

Comment: Thanks. At least I found simply omit Httptest1.test1() from my code and start with $ iex -S mix and Httptest1.test1 manually then it works. My another question is why the .ex file specified directly works when it is not placed at ./lib.

Comment: Because then it's not compiled with your project. It's run (and compiled) when you do `mix run ...` which will have your HTTPoison up and running already.

Comment: In other words, `$ mix run httptest1.ex` compiles files under lib and dependent modules but only runs ./httptest1.ex after HTTPoison started, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Improved! Now I know how to create an executable invoked command line.

program;

```
defmodule Httptest1 do
  use Application
  require HTTPoison

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false
    children = []
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Httptest1.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  def main(args) do # entry point
    ret = HTTPoison.get! "http://www.yahoo.com"
    %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: _, body: body} = ret # no status code matching now
    IO.inspect body
  end

end
```

and mix.exs (both created by `$ mix new httptest1 --sup` supervisor option);

```
defmodule Httptest1.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :httptest1,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     escript: escript,  # <<<< Added 
     deps: deps]
  end

  def escript do # define escript 
    [main_module: Httptest1]
  end

  def application do
    [applications: [:logger, :httpoison],
     mod: {Httptest1, []}] # 
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:httpoison, "~> 0.6"}
    ]
  end
end
```

Then in the iex invoked by `$ iex -S mix` type `Httptest.test1`, the expected result comes up! Thanks.

Also, to create command line executable,

```
   $ mix escript.build
```

then ./httptest1 is generated. Done.